# Get next value from a PySpark DataFrame column based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a dataset such as:

| date | is_business_day |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 0 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 |
| 2023-01-06 | 1 |
| 2023-01-07 | 0 |
| 2023-01-08 | 0 |
| 2023-01-09 | 1 |
| 2023-04-06 | 1 |
| 2023-04-07 | 0 |
| 2023-04-08 | 0 |
| 2023-04-09 | 0 |
| 2023-04-10 | 1 |

I would like to get the next value from `date` column when condition `is_business_day == 1` was met

The desired output would be something like:

| date | is_business_day | next_business_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 0 | 2023-01-02 |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 2023-01-03 |
| 2023-01-03 | 1 | 2023-01-04 |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 2023-01-05 |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 | 2023-01-06 |
| 2023-01-06 | 1 | 2023-01-09 |
| 2023-01-07 | 0 | 2023-01-09 |
| 2023-01-08 | 0 | 2023-01-09 |
| 2023-01-09 | 1 | 2023-01-10 |
| 2023-01-10 | 1 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-11 | 0 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-12 | 0 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-13 | 0 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2023-01-14 | 1 | ... |

I have created a function such as below:

```py
def next_business_day(df_calendar, date):
    date_f = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    next_day = (date_f + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    # Filtering DataFrame to only get the dates AFTER the date that we
    # are checking.
    df_calendar_next_days = df_calendar.filter(col('date') >= next_day)

    # Creates an `list` that contains all rows from DataFrame
    # so we can iterate over it.
    df_it = df_calendar_next_days.collect()

    is_business_day = 0
    while is_business_day == 0:
        for row in df_it:
            is_business_day = row['is_business_day']

            # If is "is_business_day == 1" then return the date
            # else iterate over the next row of DataFrame
            if is_business_day == 1:
                return row['date']
```

The function works but I can't use this function on ".withColum()" because I can't pass the DataFrame as parameter.

If I try to do a code like this:

```py
df_calendar = (
    df_calendar
        .withColumn('next_business_day', next_business_day(df_calendar, col('date')))
)
```

I receive the error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: DataFrame[date: date] of type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't debug what is wrong with the current code but what you want to achieve can be done with Pyspark's built-in function.

With conditional `F.min` function, it will look for the minimum date when `is_business_day == 1` and only look up from the next row(current row + 1).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.orderBy('date').rowsBetween(Window.currentRow + 1, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = df.withColumn('next_business_day', F.min(F.when(F.col('is_business_day') == 1, F.col('date'))).over(w))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, that works! I need to learn Window Functions as soon as possible.